# Git: What's would be the correct way of merging (or rebasing) code based on an old commit/tag that was not being tracked by git?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, workflow, rebase

### The premise:

Lets say git repository's `master` branch is currently tagged `v4.0`.

At some point (years ago) someone grabbed a clone of a `v2.0` tag and made a bunch of changes to it, but didn't maintain his own branch or even kept his code under git.

To make things even worse the biggest problem is that he had grabbed a commit off a branch that was actually a child of this `v2.0` tag, and that branch is now gone (must've been a rebase, not 100% sure). So I don't really have the **exact** common ancestor.

### What works:

A diff between the untracked code against `v2.0` can be applied *almost* (w/some Fuzz) cleanly up to a certain point in the current commit history (around our `v2.7` tag), however after `v3.0` major stuff changed (directories moved, files renamed, etc) and that diff obviously stops working there.

So a branch can be created off of anything `v2.0..v2.7` in the current repository to try and keep the old code *somehow* tracked.

### The question:

What would be the correct way of properly merging this untracked code into a branch that is ***closer*** to `master`?

I've never had to **rebase** anything, but if my understanding of the concept is correct, I would be effectively pushing the `master`'s branch commits into my new branch where I applied the diff (against the `v2.0` *era*), which I can then attempt to merge back into the `master` branch afterwards.

My flow/process just never succeeds, when the `v2.8..v3.0` commits start to pop up the conflicts become pretty unmanageable, it's as if commits were grabbed ***after*** the original clone (some patches fail because they *seem* already applied) and it's making a mess of everything (or perhaps, as I've mentioned, my original choice for a common ancestor is just wrong).

If finding the correct/closest common ancestor is paramount, is there a *git way* to do such a thing? All I can think of is making a script that would count diff lines between the old code against each commit in a range and return the one commit that produces the smallest diff.

### TL;DR

Are there proper procedures/methods/tools/alternatives for merging **branched-out, untracked, old** code into a recent~ish branch in git?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've never had to rebase anything, but if my understanding of the concept is correct, I would be effectively pushing the master's branch commits into my new branch where I applied the diff (against the v2.0 era), which I can then attempt to merge back into the master branch afterwards.

No: a `git checkout oldBranch; git rebase master` would replay the commits from `oldBranch` on top of `master`.

Then, a merge back to `master` would be a trivial fast-forward merge.
But a rebase is not a practical solution here (too many commits to replay, too many conflicts)

> Are there proper procedures/methods/tools/alternatives for merging branched-out, untracked, old code into a recent~ish branch in git?.

A merge (merge `master` into your old branch) is preferable to replay lots of old commits (which would introduce conflicts for each commit replayed).

In that merge (first from `master` to your branch), you would solve those conflicts once (to create a stable merge commit), in isolation in your old branch.
That won't be easy (there is no miracle solution to render an old code compatible with a more recent one), but at least you are dealing with *one* commit (a merge commit) to fix.

Once you are satisfied that your merge is working, you can merge back to `master`.

Comment: I'm kind of leaning towards that, except the amount of conflicts that have shown up during a merge is also _big_, which I believe is related to the problem of the unknown common ancestor. One thing that I'm working on is creating a list of patches (with `format-patch`) from "around the time" this old code took off, and reverse applying them (straight patch -R) backwards against the old code. I believe if I can make the old code 100% match an old commit I can get a better diff to work off `master`.

Comment: Besides that, my idea was to rebase `master` onto the branch where I inserted the old code, not the old code into `master`, as that is, as you said, just one big commit.

Comment: @Javier I understand. The idea is to take your time and resolve those conflicts in your branch, then merge it back to the main branch. Rebase will only increase the conflicts.

Comment: first, thanks a lot for the time and patience. I think I understood now, just one last clarification: what you propose is branching out at the common ancestor (where the code still _works_, I'll call it `oldpos` for the double meaning) committing the old code there, then merge `master` into `oldpos`, fix the conflicts that arise (hopefully fewer), and finally merge `oldpos` back into `master`?

Comment: @Javier that is the idea, yes.